# How send folder as attachments in Jenkins Job Email Notification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have A Jenkins Job with Workspace C:\hello_world\test_output*

in the test output folder, 2 things are one folder and one HTML file I want to send test output folder as a zip file as attachments  on Jenkin jobs but I can't able to do  it, please help

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as two steps: 1) zipping the files; and 2) sending the attachment.

I've done this by installing 7zip, then running the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r C:\hellow_world\test_output.zip C:\job\test_output\* - mem=AES256
```

With the https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext plugin installed, there's a lot of flexibility, including the ability to send attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that some mail hosts example GMAIL have started blocking things like executables, even when found within zip files. If you've got users on such a host, you might run into trouble through no fault of your own.

Apart from that, depending on the OS that Jenkins is running on, you could add a post-build Execute shell or Execute Windows Batch command step that calls the zip tool of your choice, and send an e-mail with attachments using the email-ext plugin for example